# How do I specify custom CSS class for a Yii field?

Tags: php, css, yii, yii2

I tried

```
  <?= $form->field($model, 'q', array('class' => 'form-control input-lg')) ?>
```

and

```
  <?= $form->field($model, 'q', ['class' => 'form-control input-lg']) ?>
```

It gives the following error

> ReflectionException
>   Class form-control input-lg does not exist

The docs were no help and didn't give examples.

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-widgets-activeform.html#field()-detail

The guide even shows the above format for a button!

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-input-forms.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'q')->textInput(['class' => 'form-control input-lg']); ?>
```

**Edit:**
As suggested by @soju

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'q', ['inputOptions' => ['class' => 'form-control input-lg']])
```

Comment: Or `$form->field($model, 'q', ['inputOptions' => ['class' => 'form-control input-lg']])`

Answer (score 3):

When you don't specify any method for field it automatically treats it as a textInput by default.

Use:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'q')->textInput(['class' => 'form-control input-lg']); ?>
```

Comment: How id your answer different from @ıɹnʇɐɹʇıʞuɐ

Comment: @crafter I know the answer is same but I tried to explain the reason that's it.

Comment: upvote for taking the time to explain what the issue is, in addition to providing a solution.